# How to see which network map you are connected to?

Tags: networking, corda

I have a three node set up using the cordapp example. The three nodes are sitting on seperate machines. I am trying to connect the three up, but cannot find a suitable test that will prove all three nodes are connected.

**Issue one**
The main issue is that i am unable to prove that the partyA node is connected to the correct network map.
(On the back of this point, is there a test that will fail if the party nodes are not connected to a network map? - this will help me prove the two nodes (network map and party) are connected as a bare minimum.)

**Issue 2**
Further to this, i have tried to send a transaction from partyA to partyB.
The error i get is below

```
No matching constructor found:
- [int, Party]: Could not parse as a command: Could not find a Party with name C=US,L=New York,O=PartyB
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
```

**What have i changed**
The only changes has been the node.conf files for partyA/partyB which have the following lines:

```
networkMapService {
    address="<controller-ip>:10002"
    legalName="O=Controller,L=London,C=GB"
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Reading through the docs here i found this `If null, or missing the node is declaring itself as the NetworkMapService host.` - implies a solution for **issue one**, however I still can't find a way to prove a node has committed to a network map; be it itself or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to check whether you are connected to the correct network map is by writing an RPC client that connects to a node and calls `CordaRPCOps.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name` to check that it is on the same network map as some other party. For example:

```
val partyBX500Name = CordaX500Name.parse(partyBName)
val partyB = rpcProxy.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(partyBX500Name)
```

You can see an example here: https://github.com/joeldudleyr3/ping-pong/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/pingpong/Client.kt.

Alternatively, you could print the names of all the nodes on the network as follows:

```
val networkMapSnapshot = proxy.networkMapSnapshot()
val nodeNames = networkMapSnapshot
                    .flatMap { it.legalIdentities }
                    .map { it.name }
```

Comment: Is there a way to see all the x500 names that a single node can see? I have used the command `run wellKnownPartyFromX500Name x500Name: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"` but that only works if you know the x500 you are looking for. Is there a way to get a list of all the nodes you can see?

Comment: Sure. Edited my answer above.